# Can we increase the size of configmap to store binary data of size more than 1 MB?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am trying to upload a jar file in a config map. I am able to upload the small jar file of size 1 MB but not a file of size 4MB. I am using below command to create configmap.

`kubectl create configmap configmap-test --from-file=jarfile.jar`

Is there a way to increase this size limit?

Client version is GitVersion:"v1.14.1" and server version is GitVersion:"v1.15.0"

Answer (score 4):

It is the constraint from the ETCD.

> The limit is 1MB because that's the limit for etcd.[size limit](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19781)

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix this you should change [Request size limit](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/dev-guide/limit.md#request-size-limit) by changing `--max-request-bytes` option

> etcd is designed to handle small key value pairs typical for metadata.
>   Larger requests will work, but may increase the latency of other
>   requests. By default, the maximum size of any request is 1.5 MiB. This
>   limit is configurable through --max-request-bytes flag for etcd
>   server.

Comment: Thanks VKR. Could you please let me know how can I set the flag `--max-request-bytes` for etcd server? I am new to this.

Comment: https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/op-guide/configuration.md#configuration-flags

Comment: The way I tried, its not helping. I am running a minikube setup. i modified the `etcd.yaml` present under `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/` by including `- --max-request-bytes=7864320` and killed the pod `etcd-minikube` in namespace `kube-system`.  Due to which it was restarted again, but still i am not able to create the config map with large files.